# android error drives me crazy

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I'm new to android developing, using eclipse Luna,

When I create my first blank activity project as my book says there should be a layout file (for designing visually the app) in the path"res/layout",
for instance a file named "MyFirstapp.xml" but in my case the layout folder is empty!

I mean there is no where yo see the designing window.

please help me with this problem.

Comment: File-based resource names must start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: MyFirstapp.xml is an example!

Comment: I've tried upper and lower case letters

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: ust I need the *.xml file in the layout folder in order to start doing myproject :(
I've watched a lot of tutorials but none of them has my problem.

Comment: Right click on the `res/layout` folder, New, Android XML file... give it a **valid name** (only `a...z0...9._` no upper case, no numbers at the beginning, no spaces)

Comment: Hey guys, my project has some errors at the creation time, which I do not know what causes them! these errors prevent my project to load thoroughly!
So it's not logical instead of solving them, run away from them !

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a new file in the res/layout folder.
2. Name it e.g. sample_layout.xml
3. Create a xml based layout or use the graphical interface for it.

Sample code from Android Developers Website:
(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Afterwards you can use the layout by calling:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);
}
```

4. If you want to get into Android developing please make sure you study Android Developer website:

http://developer.android.com/

There are tons of examples and tutorials!